# Non-reduced curve of arithmetic genus $0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a $1$-dimensional proper finite type scheme over field $k$, such that $p_a(C)=0$ (or equivalently $h^0(\mathcal{O}_C)-h^1(\mathcal{O}_C)=1$), then is it true that the reduced curve $C_{red}$ is a tree of rational curves and conics over $k$?

Comment: Not, that is not true.  Let $C_\text{red}$ be a smooth, projective, geometrically  connected $k$-curve of arithmetic genus  $g>0$.  Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $C_\text{red}$ of degree $2g-1$.  Let $\mathcal{O}_C$ be the sheaf of algebras $\mathcal{O}_{C_\text{red}} \oplus \mathcal{L}\epsilon$ with the unique $\mathcal{O}_{C_\text{red}}$-bilinear multiplication law such that $\epsilon^2$ is zero.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! If $C$ appears as degeneration of a family of ration curves, could the example above happen? Can we say more about $C_{red}$ in this case?

Comment: For every proper flat morphism to Spec of a DVR whose geometric generic fiber is a smooth, connected curve, after a finite (ramified) extension of the DVR, normalization of the fiber product, and blowing up over singular points of the closed fiber, the central fiber is "semistable" in the sense that it is a geometrically reduced and connected curve that has only ordinary double points as singularities.  Thus, it is a tree of rational curves.  So your original closed fiber is the image of a surjective, finite morphism from a tree of rational curves.

Comment: Typo correction: "Thus, it is a tree of rational curves." --> "If the geometric generic fiber is a rational curve, then the semistable closed fiber is a tree of rational curves."

Comment: @JasonStarr Just to make sure, here the semi-stability is not the one in the usual sense as we do not require each genus $0$ component has at least $3$ intersection with other components?

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  A semistable curve is *stable* if every genus $0$ irreducible component has at least $3$ special points, and every genus $1$ component has at least $1$ special point.  A variety (of arbitrary dimension) is *semistable* if it is etale locally isomorphic to a simple normal crossings divisor in a smooth ambient variety.  So a semistable curve is a geometrically reduced curve that has only ordinary double points.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! sorry for that, I took stable for semistable...

Comment: @JasonStarr would you mind pointing me to a reference for your statements about the structure of the special fiber?